# Get unknown value in discrete random variable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable

(i) Assume that the PMF of $X$ is given by
$$\operatorname{Pr}(X=x)=\begin{cases}kx^{2} & x \in \{-4,-2,0,2,4\} \\ 0 & x\not\in \{-4, -2, 0, 2, 4\}\end{cases}$$

I got the value $k=1/40, \quad E(x) = 0$

Then I have $y= 0.5 x + 3$, I need to get the value of $E(y)$ and $Var(y)$!

From the formula I got the pmf of $y$ which $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ otherwise $0$

Is my pmf of y correct? And 
How I can continue now to get the $E(y)$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: total probability is $1$.